# Switching between similar routes in React Router

Tags: reactjs, flux, react-router

I have this kind of route:

```
<Route name="itemDetails" handler={ItemDetails} path="/item/:itemId"/>
```

It leads to the page, containing full product description.
There are few "related items". Each of them contains the Link to the different "itemDetails" page. When I'm clicking on one of this links, the route is changing in browser address bar, but the content is not.
Why? The rest of routes works well.
Also, if i reload the page, content is refreshing and it's mutching to the route in browser address bar

It might be because of the incorrect url listener
It tried this:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('example'));
});
```

and this:

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, function (Root) {
  React.render(React.createElement(Root, null), document.body);
});
```

Here the itemDetails code:

```
var React = require('react');
var Store = require('../../stores/app-store');
var Preloader = require('../template/app-preloader');
var NewEstateItem = require('./app-newestateitem');
var NewEstateRelated = require('./app-newestaterelated');

var NewEstateDetails = React.createClass({




    getInitialState: function() {
    return { item: null };
  },


  componentWillMount: function() {
    itemId = this.props.params.itemId;
    console.log('ItemId:', itemId);
    Store.getNewEstateById(itemId,this._getNewEstateDetails);
  },

    render: function() {
        var item = this.state.item;
    if(!item) {
      return (<Preloader />);
    }
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="container flex-container">
                    <div className="col s12 m12 l8">
                        <div className="col s12">
                            <h4>{item.Name}</h4>
                        </div>
                    <div className="col l4 hide-on-med-and-down margintop">
                    <h5 className="center">Related items</h5>
                        <div className="col s12">
                            <NewEstateRelated Price={item.Price}/>      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    _getNewEstateDetails: function (item) {
    this.setState({item:item});
  }

});

module.exports = NewEstateDetails;
```

And here relatedItem Link code:

```
<Link to="ItemDetails" params={{itemId: item.objectId, CustomID: item.CustomID}} className="btn</Link>
```

Here the store:

```
var getNewEstateData = {

  getNewEstateById: function(objectId, callback) {
    console.log('store.objectId', objectId);
    function NewEstateData() {};
    var item = Backendless.Persistence.of( NewEstateData ).findById( objectId );
    console.log("store.getNewEstateById", item);
    callback(item);
  },

  getAllNewEstate: function(callback) {
    function NewEstateData() {};
    var items = Backendless.Persistence.of( NewEstateData ).find().data;
    callback(items)
  },

  getRelatedNewEstateItems: function (priceBottom, priceTop, callback) {
    function NewEstateData() {};
    var items = Backendless.Persistence.of( NewEstateData );
    var dataQuery = {
      condition: "Price >= "+priceBottom
    }
    var query = items.find( dataQuery ).data
    var output = query.slice(0,3)
    console.log('relatedItems', query);
    callback(output)
  }
};

module.exports = getNewEstateData;
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the code from ItemDetails. Are you doing anything with router.getCurrentParams().id in the render method there?

Comment: about this: router.getCurrentParams().id
i don't. What and how should i do with it?

Comment: It could be that componentDidMount is only being called on the first render and that's the only place the state is being updated with the selected item - looks like router.getCurrentParams().itemId is the same as doing this.props.params.itemId

Comment: How  can I add listener, which will trigger some method on path change?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the issue:

Your router is expecting `:id`:

```
<Route name="itemDetails" handler={ItemDetails} path="/item/:id"/>
```

But you are sending `itemId` in the `<link>`:

```
<Link to="ItemDetails" params={{itemId: item.objectId, CustomID: item.CustomID}} className="btn</Link>
```

I am pretty sure it should match and be:

```
<Link to="ItemDetails" params={{id: item.objectId, CustomID: item.CustomID}} className="btn</Link>
```

See the docs for it [here](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Link) where the example confirms this:

> params: An object of the names/values that correspond with dynamic segments in your route path.

**Docs Example**

```
// given a route config like this
<Route name="user" path="/users/:userId"/>

// create a link with this
<Link to="user" params={{userId: "123"}}/>

// though, if your user properties match up to the dynamic segements:
<Link to="user" params={user}/>
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault - typo in this description. I've corrected it

Comment: Are you sure the data in the store is different? The only thing I can think of is that your store is actually returning the same data so the UI doesn't update.

Comment: checked: the data in the store is not different. Why?

Comment: I don't know why your store hasn't returned different content....Without seeing all the code I cannot help you. Looks like this question is kind of invalid as the routes are indeed working, it's your stores that are not!

Comment: Post up your store and other relevant code to see if it helps decipher the issue.

Comment: Sure, I will post it in few minutes.
I've noticed, that in the ItemDetails component, method componentDidMount is not triggered. It strange.

Comment: i've added the store to the description

Comment: I'm afraid There is nothing in the store that stands out to me, sorry. It could be an issue with your data on the server. I knew the router issue, not the store issue. You may want to ask another question or edit the title of this one to get the attention you need for the newly identified problem. An upvote for at least getting the correct answer from your typo would be good though ;) Good luck!